# SFML - sf::RenderWindow, dividing files

Tags: c++, sfml

so it is probably something trival but I really need to know why it does happen the way it does and how can I change it.

So I started to learn SFML today and I was reading SFML Game Development ebook and saw very interesting and well written code. I went through tutorials about SFML and started to learn language as I understood general idea of way how it should work.

So I wanted to remember new keywords, constructors, methods but also make my code well organized - using what I have learned to keep it clean and easy to edit, debug.

My first code was to display Window and I created same code in both ways, normally putting everything to main function and separated. Thing is that first Window is displayed as long as I won't close it and second one is displaying for less than second and program is turning off.

It probably because destructor is called right after I turn it on and adding more functions to keep object busy is way to go but well, I want to understand it. It's last thing which I don't really understand as I learned objective programming. The way objects are working. Right after I create them, I am using them for certain task, but then when I am done they are being deleted, well sometimes I need them again. I just wish to understand how does it work and find really easy and quick fix/idea to make it work as long as I want it to.

Code :

**First program:**

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

int main()
{
    sf::RenderWindow mainWindow(sf::VideoMode(800,600),"Main Window");

    while(mainWindow.isOpen())
    {
        sf::Event openEvent;
        while(mainWindow.pollEvent(openEvent))
        {
            switch(openEvent.type)
            {
                case sf::Event::Closed:
                mainWindow.close();
                break;
            }
            mainWindow.clear();
            mainWindow.display();
        }
    }
}
```

**Second program:**

**main.cpp**

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include "Game.cpp"

int main()
{
    Game game;
    game.run();
}
```

**Game.cpp**

```
#include "Game.h"

    Game::Game()
    {
        sf::RenderWindow mainWindow(sf::VideoMode(800,600),"Main Window");
    }

    void Game::run()
    {
        while(mainWindow.isOpen())
        {
            sf::Event openEvent;
            while(mainWindow.pollEvent(openEvent))
            {
                switch(openEvent.type)
                {
                    case sf::Event::Closed:
                    mainWindow.close();
                    break;
                }
            }
            mainWindow.clear();
            mainWindow.display();
        }
    }
```

**Game.h**

```
class Game
{
    public:
    Game();
    void run();

    private:
    sf::RenderWindow mainWindow;

};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Game::Game()
{
    sf::RenderWindow mainWindow(sf::VideoMode(800,600),"Main Window");
}
```

In your constructor here, you are creating a new `RenderWindow` object, which is immediately destroyed once the constructor exits. What you want to do is initialize the `RenderWindow` which is a member of your class. You can do that in one of two ways, either using the `RenderWindow` constructor in the member initializer list:

```
Game::Game()
    :mainWindow(sf::VideoMode(800,600),"Main Window")
{}
```

Or calling the `create` function in the constructor body like following:

```
Game::Game()
{
    mainWindow.create(sf::VideoMode(800,600),"Main Window");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for an answer :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to change this:

```
Game::Game()
{
    sf::RenderWindow mainWindow(sf::VideoMode(800,600),"Main Window");
}
```

To this:

```
Game::Game() : mainWindow(sf::VideoMode(800,600),"Main Window");
{

}
```

In the first example, you're creating an `sf::RenderWindow` within the constructor, then destroying it immediately, whereas in the second example, you're initializing the member-variable version, which will keep your window as long as the `Game` object that contains it is not destroyed (or as long as you don't manually destroy the window).

Comment: Oh, exactly it is how it was written in book which I read, I just didn't understood it completly. Your explanation made it clear for me. Big thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Your second program should be working with one small Change.

You already have a variable called mainWindow of type RenderWindow. Instead of creating it the way you are doing, you'll have to use the create() function within the mainWindow.

```
Game::Game()
{
     mainWindow.create(sf::VideoMode(800,600),"Main Window");
}
```

Just a tip, generally you don't want to be using the isOpen() for the game-loop. I recommend you look into enum classes.

Here is a great video explaining how you would use them.

[link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Pxvvr5FAWxg)

Comment: Thanks, I will check it. Why shouldn't I use isOpen() ? I mean, I saw this in code of people who actually created SFML library so is there really any reason why is it bad to use it ? I didn't learned a lot about enums, I did one lesson about it and used it sometimes for college projects but I didn't found it necessary for smaller programs which I was writting right now and this way I completly forgot about using enums at all. Could you help me with reasoning it and giving some examples where it actually saves you some time/makes code easier to read/edit ?

Comment: Well for example. You know how in many games you can close the window by pressing alt+f4? Using Enum classes you can define state of games such as - MainMenu, GameStart, GameClose, Options and many other things you might have in a game, and depending on what the user does you just alter the state of your enum object. It's a very simple and useful concept. And it's clean code, so if the user presses alt+f4 you can just change the enum object to be equal to gameClose. Keeps it nice and clean.

Comment: Okay so changing this line made it work. Could you tell me why does it work this way ?

Comment: Because you are re-creating another window from the one that previously existed (the one you created in the .h file). That's not what you want. You want to initialize the one you first create in the .h file so that you can use it in other funcitons.

Comment: alt+f4 sends a close event to the window. So it will close just fine by checking `isOpen()`.